# Syntax explanation for "new" keyword for contracts in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I am trying to understand the syntax of `C c = new C();`

I read the `new` keyword deploys, initializes state variables, runs the constructor, sets nonce to one, and returns address of new instance.

I read that a state variable `a` has a 0-ary public getter function `a()` that returns the value of `a`.

Questions:

1. What "is" the getter function of a contract?
2. Why does `new` act on the getter function?
3. In `C c = new C();` why do we need the first `C` to define the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A contract doesn't have a "getter" function. You could read `C()` as calling the contract's constructor (but the call isn't like regular functions).

The part `new C()` is the solidity syntax to deploy the `C` contract. The constructor accepts parameters so they can be passed like this `new D(param1, param2, param3)`.

The requirement to declare the type returned in the assignment `C c = ...` is for security reasons. A few versions back solidity supported `var c = ...` but there were a few contracts with subtle bugs due to the wrong type deduced by the compiler.

Comment: Asked a follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71461912/18381563)